# Automatic pagination in Cassandra using python

Tags: python-2.7, cassandra-2.0

I want to implement paging in my application. I found this in my research http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0 
According to this new Java driver support paging. Does python driver have similar features?

```
Statement stmt = new SimpleStatement("SELECT * FROM images");
stmt.setFetchSize(100);
ResultSet rs = session.execute(stmt);

// Iterate over the ResultSet here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, paging is supported in the DataStax Python driver for Apache Cassandra.

Please see the [docs here](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/query_paging.html).

> By default, Session.default_fetch_size controls how many rows will be fetched per page. This can be overridden per-query by setting fetch_size on a Statement. By default, each page will contain at most 5000 rows.

Comment: yeah got it, thanks man http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datastax-python-driver-2-0-released

Comment: Seems not to work. Whatever I set fetch_size, I receive a `ResultSet` instead of a `PagedResults` object.